# Subversive "/ by zero" error when committing

Tags: eclipse, subversive

We have installed (on several machines) the ADT and afterwards the Subversive plugin plus the Polarion connectors. However, each time I commit a change (with a simple HelloWorld app), I get the following message:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.progress(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.SVNProgressMonitor.progress(SVNProgressMonitor.java:63)
    at org.polarion.team.svn.connector.svnkit.SVNKitConnector$CommitInfo.commitInfo(SVNKitConnector.java:2518)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl$10.receive(SVNClientImpl.java:1947)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl$10.receive(SVNClientImpl.java:1)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnReceivingOperation.receive(SvnReceivingOperation.java:78)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCommit.run(SvnNgCommit.java:125)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCommit.run(SvnNgCommit.java:1)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
```

It could not find any indication on the internet that this is a problem, but on the other hand, two independently installed machines with two different small test projects generated the same problem.

*The source code appears properly on our SVN server and we get a revision number.* But obviously, we don't feel overly comfortable working like that.

In terms of versions, everything is up to date and was installed last week.

Thanks for any indication

Comment: yeah that's a heavy hitter, got the same issue. Would be so great if someone could share a solution.

Comment: Yep, same problem here after updating subversive.

Answer (score 3):

So I believe I solved this. I updated Subversive (Subversive SVN Team Provider) to 1.1.3. I had to add Subversive's update site (`http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.1/update-site/`) to Eclipse's update repository for the latest versions to show up.

I've tested a few commits without incident. Before it was 100% of my commits, so sounds fixed to me.